# How to delete record in case of bi directional many to many mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables one is `Employee` and the other is `Depts`. I have implemented a bidirectional many-to-many mapping between them using a third table `EMPLOYEE_DEPT`. Now I want to delete an employee and all it's departments from `Depts` table. How can I do that?

I tried

```
Set setOfEmp = dept.getEmployees();     
for(Object obj : setOfEmp){
    Employee emp= (Employee)obj;
    emp.removeDept(dept);
}
deptManager.removeDepartment(dept);
```

and then deleting the employee as follows :

```
empManager.removeEmployee(emp);
```

This gave me the error

> optimistic locking failed (nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction`)

Second approach that I tried is removing department from employee first and deleting

```
emp.getDept().remove(dept);
dept.getEmployees().remove(emp);
empManager.removeEmployee(emp);
deptManager.removeDepartment(dept);
```

This gave me the error

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C007682) violated - child record found

Apart from the above code the code for saving is as follows :

First the employee gets created and then afterwards saving  department

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setName("testingEmployee");
emp.setDept(new HashSet());
empManager.saveEmployee(emp);

Department dept = new Department();
dept.setName("testDept");
Set setOfDept = new HashSet();
setOfDept.add(dept);

Set setOfEmp = new HashSet();
setOfEmp.add(emp);
dept.setEmployees(setOfEmp);
emp.setDept(setOfDept);
empManager.saveEmployee(emp);
deptManager.saveDept(dept);
```

The mapping for both of them in Hibernate goes like:

```
<set name="departments" table="EMP_DEPTS" lazy="false" cascade = "all">
    <key column="EMP_ID"/>
    <many-to-many class="com.model.Department" column="DEPT_ID"/>
</set>
```

This is the set mapping of `Department` in the `Employee` `.hbm` file.Aand for set of employees mapping in the `Department` `.hbm` is as follows:

```
<set name="employees" table="EMP_DEPTS" inverse="true" lazy="true">
    <key column="DEPT_ID"/>
    <many-to-many class="com.model.Employee" column="EMP_ID"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Your issue seems to be linked to transaction management. Could you include the whole code between the start of the transaction and the end of it ?